# STM32 reading variables out of Received Buffer with variable size

Tags: variables, buffer, stm32, transformation, uart

I am not really familiar with programming in STM32. I am using the micro controller STM32F303RE.

I am receiving data via a UART connection with DMA.

Code:

```
HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart2, RxBuf, RxBuf_SIZE);
__HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart2_rx, DMA_IT_HT);
```

I am writing the value into a Receiving Buffer and then transfer it into a main buffer. This function and declaration is down before the int main(void).

```
#define RxBuf_SIZE 100
#define MainBuf_Size 100

uint8_t RxBuf[RxBuf_SIZE];
uint8_t MainBuf[MainBuf_Size];

void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart,uint16_t Size){
    if( huart -> Instance == USART2){
        memcpy (MainBuf, RxBuf, Size);
        HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart2, RxBuf, RxBuf_SIZE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<Size; i++){
        if((MainBuf[i] == 'G') && (MainBuf[i+1] == 'O')){
            RecieveData();
            HAL_UART_DMAStop(&huart2);
        }
    }
}
```

I receive know the data into a buffer and it stops as soon as "GO" is transmitted. Until this point it is working. The function `ReceiveData()` should then transform this buffer to the variables. But it isn't working for me.

Now I want to transform this received data with "breakpoints" into variables.

So I want to send: "S2000S1000S1S10S2GO".

I always have 5 variables. (in this case: 2000, 1000, 1, 10, 2) I want to read the data out of the string and transform it into an uint16_t to procude. The size/ length of the variables could be changed. That's why I tried to use like some breakpoint.

Comment: Why don't you show us the function that isn't working?

Comment: The function is empty now. I don't know how I can do this transformation. that's why I asked here if someone could give me some advice on how to solve this problem or even could show some code/function I could use.